# YAML: Anchors for keys?

Tags: yaml

Can I reuse keys in YAML without retyping them? If it's possible to repeat the key by the anchor, renaming this key will be simple.

```
splitTestVariants:
  lowCost: 0
  mediumCost: 1
  highCost: 2

pricePlans:
  # reuse lowCost key instead this comment without retyping it
    basic: 100
    premium: 200
    vip: 300
  # reuse mediumCost key instead this comment without retyping it
    basic: 200
    premium: 300
    vip: 400
  # reuse highCost instead this comment without retyping it
    basic: 300
    premium: 400
    vip: 500
```

Comment: What you probably want to ask is if you can use aliases for keys. There is no need  for the anchors for such aliases to be keys as well, in particular if you never going to use the values 0, 1, and 2. They could e.g. be elements of a sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is possible to use anchors and aliases to reduce the typing:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
splitTestVariants:
  &l lowCost: 0
  &m mediumCost: 1
  &h highCost: 2

pricePlans:
  *l :
    basic: 100
    premium: 200
    vip: 300
  *m :
    basic: 200
    premium: 300
    vip: 400
  *h :
    basic: 300
    premium: 400
    vip: 500
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.default_flow_style = False
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
print(list(data['pricePlans'].keys()))
```

which gives:

```
['lowCost', 'mediumCost', 'highCost']
```

The above is a feature of YAML, not of `ruamel.yaml` (of
which I am the author) in particular.

Please note the space between the alias (`*X`) and the mapping value indicator (`:`). Not all YAML parsers (including `libyaml` on which the C implementation used by `ruamel.yaml` when specifying `YAML(typ='safe')') correctly parse YAML anchors and aliases, [colons can be part of an anchor name](http://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#ns-anchor-name) so the space (or a newline) is required here.